# Call sql database and get query

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create a Result page with variable my code is as under

```
<?php
$r=1
$con=mysqli_connect(localhost,chumspai_tlss,Tls121,chumspai_tlsResult);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())   {   
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ". mysqli_connect_error();   
} 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nursery_blue_ WHERE sr_="$r"");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {
   Print $row['sr_'] . "" . $row['students_names'] . " " . $row['english_50_'];
   echo "<br>";
} 
?>
```

When i use

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *FROM nursery_blue_ WHERE sr_='1'");
```

It works fine but i want to use variable please help

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nursery_blue_ WHERE sr_="1"");` how can work fine?

Comment: even i am wondering, how did it worked! are you sure?

Comment: it fines because here is no variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your line from

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nursery_blue_ WHERE sr_="$r"");
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nursery_blue_ WHERE sr_='$r'");
```

Notice the single quotes

And also change `$r=1` to `$r=1;`

Notice the semi colon

Comment: Put semi colon (;) after $r=1

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do in more cleanest way using `sprintf()` funciton

```
// Prepare a query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM nursery_blue_ WHERE sr_ = '%s'", $r);

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Answer (score 1):

change
`$r=1`  // a syntex error of semicolon

to

```
$r=1;
```

use single quote for query

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *
FROM nursery_blue_ WHERE sr_='$r'");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change on following code

```
"SELECT * FROM nursery_blue_ WHERE sr_='$r'"
```

Answer (score 0):

An other option is to break up the string:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nursery_blue_ WHERE sr_=".$r);
```

And if $r is a string:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nursery_blue_ WHERE sr_='".$r."');
```